Dual module of $\prod_{i = 1}^\infty R$
This is a rather vague question, so I apologize in advance. I would like to know for what class of rings is it known that $\displaystyle\operatorname{Hom}_R\left(\prod_{i = 1}^\infty R, R\right)$ is a free $R$-module generated by the canonical projections $\displaystyle\pi_i: \prod_{i = 1}^\infty R\to R$?
This is true for $\mathbb{Z}$ and is a theorem due to Specker which uses the following key lemma:

Lemma. Let $G = \prod_{i = 1}^\infty \mathbb{Z}$ and $H$ be the free abelian subgroup of $G$ generated by the ``standard basis vectors'' $\{e_i\colon i\geqslant 1\}$. If $f: G\to\mathbb{Z}$ is a group homomorphism that vanishes on $H$, then $f = 0$.

Proof. See Lemma 1 here.
This lemma readily generalizes to non-local Noetherian domains as seen here. But I am not able to see a direct generalization of the proof of Specker's result (Theorem 4 here) in this case (for that matter, I don't even have a counterexample). Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
